# Storing multiple values for each unique key

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to store multiple values for each key, kind of like a multidimensional array. I wrote a function that firsts checks whether the key already exists and if it does, it will simply insert the value to the end of that specific array. Here is my code:

```
$arr = array();
add_to_array($arr,"fruit","apple");
add_to_array($arr,"fruit","banana");
function add_to_array($array, $key, $value) {
  if(array_key_exists($key, $array)) {
      echo $key;
      if(is_array($array[$key])) {
          $array[$key][] = $value;
      }
      else {
          $array[$key] = array($array[$key], $value);           
      }
  echo $key;
  }
  else {
      $array[$key] = array($value);
      echo $key; // I am calling this function with the same key however, this statement gets printed out twice
      echo "\n";
  }
```

}

However, when i run this program, it seems that the key never exists even when i call it twice with the same $key parameter.

Comment: Well don't store 2 strings, store an array of strings or an object then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

```
$arr = array('fruit' => array());
$arr['fruit'][] = 'banana';
$arr['fruit'][] = 'apple';
print_r($arr);
```

...cause in that case you're kinda overcomplicating matters with your elaborate function ;)

Or I may misunderstand (I don't really *get* your function to be honest), but your problem may be as simple as this: You want to pass the first parameter as [a reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) (so whatever changes you make to it will persist) - just put an `&` in front of the variable name:

```
function add_to_array(&$array, $key, $value) {
    // [...]
}
```